# php load/get xml child by querying value of element

Tags: php, xml, post, xpath

data,value from my xml file based on the name which gets posted.

This is my xml file:

```
<object>
  <name>test 1</name>
  <data>some data</data>
  <value>1</value>
</object>
<object>
  <name>test 2</name>
  <data>some data 2</data>
  <value>2</value>
</object>
```

This is my php file:

```
$wijzignaam = $_POST['wijzignaam'];
$xmlfile = file_get_contents('../xmlfile.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xpath = $xml->xpath('object/name["'.$wijzignaam.'"]');
print_r($xpath);
```

This returns an empty array I have been looking for an answer for a while and I didn't find anything so any help is appreciated

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: it just returns an empty array like this: array();

Comment: your code producing fatal error as its not valid xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Several issues here:

1. XML has no root element, hence is not valid.
2. path in `xpath` is incomplete
3. condition in `xpath` has a wrong syntax

#### ad 1: enclose your XML with a root node, like:

```
<root>
    <object>
        <name>test 1</name>
    </object>
</root>
```

#### ad 2 and 3: path and condition syntax:

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath("/root/object[name = 'test 1']");
```

or

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath("//object[name = 'test 1']");
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/517818